# Can we populate html attribute with html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using visjs library, in the doc of this library they say that you can write plain text or HTML element inside a title attribute:

> Add a title for the item, displayed when holding the mouse on the item. The title can be an HTML element or a string containing plain text or HTML.

But when I try to populate a title attribute with HTML it takes it as a plain text:

```
item.title='<div class="tooltip"><strong>dff</strong><br/>fdkdk</div>';
```

Is there a way to make title attribute to treat it content as a HTML elements?

Comment: Do you mean an [HTML title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)?

Comment: It may not be possible but you can create a substitue of tooltip using javascript & html

Comment: thanks for your answer but its gives me an error because data-toggle its a methode of the library...that was expected..heres the link if you want to take a look:http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Templates

Comment: no its not html title attribute ..its a javascript a ttribute heres the link :http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of VIS do you use?

Just download the newest version of VIS and the html tooltip will work.

I tried it a few minutes ago with the Version v4.18.1 and it works like a charm.

```js
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function(){
var nodeSet = [{
     id: 1000,
     label: 'Root Node',
     x: -600,
     y: -400,
     physics: false,
     fixed: {
         x: true,
         y: true
     }
 }, {
     id: 1,
     label: '1: Test Tooltip with HTML',
     title: '<strong>HTML</strong> Tooltip'
 }, {
     id: 2,
     label: '1: Test Tooltip without HTML',
     title: 'NO HTML'
 }];

//
$.each(nodeSet, function(  ) {  
   this.label= this.label.replace( /(.{10})/g,"$1\n")
}); 
//

// create an array with nodes
 var nodes = new vis.DataSet(nodeSet);

 // create an array with edges
 var edges = new vis.DataSet([
 {
     from: 1000,
     to: 1
 },
 {
     from: 1000,
     to: 3
 },  {
     from: 1,
     to: 2
 }, {
     from: 3,
     to: 4
 }, {
     from: 4,
     to: 5
 },  {
     from: 3,
     to: 50
 }, {
     from: 4,
     to: 50
 }]);

 // create a network
 var container = document.getElementById('vis-exmaple');
 var data = {
     nodes: nodes,
     edges: edges
 };
 var options = {
     nodes: {
         shape: 'box',
         size: 15,         
     },
     edges:{ 
         arrows: 'to'
     }     
 };
 var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
})
 </script>
```

```css
#vis-exmaple {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js"></script>

<body>
<p>Test HTML Tooltip VIS.JS</p>
<div id="vis-exmaple"></div>
</body
```

http://visjs.org/#download_install